# git-instaweb and git-clone

Tags: git

I setup a git webserver on my local machine using git-instaweb.

Now I want to be able to clone from that repos, but when I tried

`git clone http://localhost:1234` it gives me an error:

```
fatal: http://localhost:1234/info/refs not found: did you run git update-server-info on the server?
```

`git update-server-info` didn't help. Anybody has a solution to this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Git instaweb is designed for *browsing* the repository in a web browser, rather than something you can clone from. Try going to http://localhost:1234 in your web browser to see.

If you want to clone from something, you may be looking for [git-daemon](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-daemon.html) instead.

Comment: Yes, of course, git-daemon could do that, but it would be great to use the same url, isn't it? 
Hg on the other hand would allow you to pull from http served repos. So I thought, it should be possible to do the same for git.

Comment: Git can pull from repos served with HTTP, too. But that's not what git-instaweb offers.

Comment: Excuse me, I was trying to say "pull from the SAME http served repos" which served by hg serve.

Comment: On this page, http://www.gromacs.org/Developer_Zone/Git/Git_Tutorial, it seems to suggest that it is possible,  but I sure cannot confirm that.

Comment: This is possible using [git-http-backend](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-http-backend.html), and indeed that would be a fine addition for `git-instaweb`.